# Save photos to ALAssetsGroup type:Event programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

As far as I'm concerned there are at least two types of `ALAssetsGroups` available in iOS - `Type:Album` and `Type:Event`.

I am able to save the photos to the Albums using third party libraries, simply by knowing their names, but is there a way to programmatically save photos to the Events and/or create Events programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out every `ALAssetsGroup` has a property `.isEditable` which defines the probability of adding anything into it. In `iOS 7` and earlier, groups with `Type:Event` and `Type:Faces` are not editable.